# How to open a pdf file in a WebForm application by search?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

When I click on the listbox which search a PDF file, it's not opening.

The code is below. Any thoughts?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ListBox1.Items.Clear();
  string search = TextBox1.Text;
  if (TextBox1.Text != "") 
  {
    string[] pdffiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.168.5.10\fbar\REPORT\CLOTHO\H2\REPORT\", "*" + TextBox1.Text + "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string file in pdffiles)
    {
      // ListBox1.Items.Add(file);
      ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Response.Write("<script>alert('For this Wafer ID Report is Not Generated');</script>");
  }
}

protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string pdffiles = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

  string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));

  ProcessStartInfo infoOpenPdf = new ProcessStartInfo();
  infoOpenPdf.FileName = pdffiles;
  infoOpenPdf.Verb = "OPEN";
  // Process.Start(file);
  infoOpenPdf.CreateNoWindow = true;
  infoOpenPdf.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

  Process openPdf = new Process();
  openPdf.StartInfo = infoOpenPdf;
  openPdf.Start();
}
```

Comment: Please inform to me if the code is have any problem...

Comment: Assuming that code works, it would open the PDF on the server, not the client where the web browser is running. You would need to download or write the file to the response stream.

Comment: Code may be ok. Your expectation that you can open files on client machine by running `Process.Start` on server is a problem. Since you likely already read through many [C# open PDF file in ASP.Net](https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23%20open%20pdf%20file%20in%20ASP.Net) questions/articles  it is somewhat strange that your tried to do it.

Comment: Can you give me a sample code how the client open the pdf file from the browser ? please help me....

Answer (score 1):

First, you must save the file's full name to get it later. So, you must change from:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
```

To:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(file), file));
```

---

Then, you should send the file from the server to the client, like this:

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = ListBox1.SelectedValue;
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

    System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
    context.Response.ClearContent();
    context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
    context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

---

Note: don't forget to initialize your `ListBox` with the property `AutoPostBack` setted to `true`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your code. But i still have same problem which is cannot open or view the pdf file. Please help me....

Comment: Hi Buzinas, Thanks for the code. it still cannot open the pdf file from the server in webbrowser when click on the listbox. Please help me....

Comment: @cgkumar What error are you getting? Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: No error. Yes debug it ready. But the problem is when i click on listbox one of the listed pdf file, the pdf file is cannot open.

Comment: But when you click on an item, is your event triggered? If you place a breakpoint into the first line of `ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`, and then choose an item, does this breakpoint get caught?